# What is the best way to render PartialView to a Layout Page in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

[image]There is a layout page in my `MVC5` project and I want to render all the page contents (partial views) by clicking menu links (hyperlink) on the left side as shown below. There are some methods using `Ajax`, etc. but I am not sure which approach meets my needs best. Is there any example regarding to this problem containing the `Layout` page and `Controller` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first wrap your body content in div and assign any id to it:

```
<div id="divContentArea">
@RenderBody()
</div>
```

Now in **Script Menu click event**:

```
$(".menuLinkItem").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    var controllerName = $(this).attr('data-controllername');
    var actionName = $(this).attr('data-actionname'); 

    if (String(actionName).trim() == '') {
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof (controllerName) == "undefined") {
        return false;
    }

    var url = "/" + controllerName + "/" + actionName;

    //Open url in new tab with ctrl key press
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }            

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            var requestedUrl = String(this.url).replace(/[&?]X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest/i, "");
            if (typeof (requestedUrl) == "undefined" || requestedUrl == 'undefined') {
                requestedUrl = window.location.href;
            }

            // if the url is the same, replace the state
            if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
                if (window.location.href == requestedUrl) {
                    history.replaceState({ html: '' }, document.title, requestedUrl);
                }
                else {
                    history.pushState({ html: '' }, document.title, requestedUrl);
                }
            }

            $("#divContentArea").html(data);                

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
        }
    });

});
```

**Controller:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public PartialViewResult Index()
{
        if (HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. There is a little problem. After trying to pass the **success: function (data) {** line by using Firebug, there is an error **ReferenceError: data is not defined**. I also tried to define a data parameter and assing an integer value for testing but did not make any sense. Any idea?

Comment: May there be a parameter not defined at this example like **data**?

Comment: Ok, I realized that I needed to use *[AllowAnonymous]* in my Controller method. Now it is working like a charm :) Many thanks for your answer...

Comment: After rendering the partial view I see that clicking the browser's refresh button cause "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:43239/Account/_Register". Any idea? How to make the refresh button forward the Index page?

Comment: i have update my answer please check it : Controller action call change

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, but in that case what about the POST method for creating records? The code hits to the same action and will return the View instead of creating a new record using the POST method? It can be solved using a different name for the POST method, but I am not sure if it is a pretty solution.

Comment: Rendering partialview takes too log time and I detected that the time consuming part of the AJAX method is on the success part (until the line of $("#divContentArea").html('');). Are they (mentioned lines) necessary in this solution? Because it takes too long time?

Comment: Can I know reason for down vote and unacceptable after to many days?

Comment: I just change the selected answer, vote down by mistake. I just have opportunity to test this and saw the problem. For this reason I selected as unanswer so that you can suggest another solution to fix the problem and the others can also benefit from your answer. On the other hand the problem may be related to tje Action method. I am waiting your valuable opinions for fixing the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it take time,  check your partial view render code.  If blank partial view not take time then you have to check   your view html

Comment: Thanks, I tried with an empty PartialView that is only some letters for content, but the result is the same and it takes 5 seconds to render this PartialView. It is really unbelievable that the Action method cause to wait 5 seconds. But it is a standard Action method and there may be another effect causing this problem. Any idea?

Comment: have you applied any filter on action? any other database Or view call on menu item click, it may be take time.

Comment: No, there is no filter on action and no database operation during the render process. I just use a menu item to render partialview.

Comment: Then it should not take such long time in render partial view

Comment: It is your internal issue to load view, i can only help you how to load partial view on menu click in this question, why it take more time is out of this question scope. there are so many reason behind this. you have to debug and check which code cause performance issue

Comment: The rendering process get short time after the first loading. I mean that when debugging project, the first time I render partialview, it takes 5 seconds, but the latter rendering takes short time. Is it just caching issue? Is that normal the first rendering takes too long time?

Comment: Yes, but not as much long 5 sec, please check your browser page render log where it take time

Comment: I checked using Firebug and there is no error on Console. I also look at the Network tab and the only indicator on 5 seconds is "waiting". How can I debug it? By adding console.log() to several lines in AJAX call? Any other method to debug it?

Comment: Any idea for the last comment?

Comment: You can log time in console for code line where required and check where it take time to execute

Comment: Many thanks for your kind helps. Just a last point regarding to AJAX call: Would it be better to use **$("#divContentArea").html(data);** instead of the 2 line codes at that section? Because it seems to be better to change the div content instead of clear and append. What is your opinion?

Comment: If the approach is OK could you please update answer?

Comment: Thanks... Voted+++ :)