# How to display different search results without page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, search, razor

I'm writing an asp.net website that has a search. Depending on the filter that they apply, the results will be different (Look and Data displayed). Are partial views the best way to go about this? I don't want the page to have to refresh every time they apply a new filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, partial view is best approach** for this, use ajax call to load partial view.

Please refer for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38968860/6606630

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are reffering to Ajax tech?

Check this link: http://www.asp.net/ajax