# How to apply filters using fetch in asp.net 6

Tags: asp.net, ajax, fetch

I'd like to apply the filters to the list cars without reloading the page. While I was looking how to do it, I followed few advices and tried fetch API but I have no idea how to use it.

So far I have my index page
@model IEnumerable<GarageVParrot.Models.Car>

### Nos véhicules d'occasion

```
<aside class="filters">
    <div class="filter-filter">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between main-filter-buttons">
            <h3 class="filter">Filtres</h3>
            <i class="bi bi-chevron-down " onclick="showFilter('filter')"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('filter')"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="filter-box-open" id="filter-filter-box">
                <div class="brand-filter box-filter" id="brand">
                    <div class="filter-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4>MARQUE</h4>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('brand')"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('brand')"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="brand-filter-box">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.DistinctBy(i => i.Brand).OrderBy(i => i.Brand))
                        {
                            var uniqueId = "brand-" + item.Id;
                            <div class="filter-box-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="@uniqueId" name="car-brand" value="@item.Brand"  />
                                <label for="car-brand" class="control-label">@item.Brand</label>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="model-filter box-filter" id="model">
                        <div class="filter-model d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                            <h4>MODELE</h4>
                            <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('model')"></i>
                            <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('model')"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="model-filter-box">
                            @foreach (var item in Model.DistinctBy(i => i.Model).OrderBy(i => i.Model))
                            {
                                var uniqueId = "model-" + item.Id;
                                <div class="filter-box-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="@uniqueId" name="car-model" value="@item.Model" onclick="filter(brand)"/>
                                    <label for="car-model" class="control-label">@item.Model</label>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="category-filter box-filter" id="category">
                    <div class="filter-category d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4>CATEGORY</h4>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('category')"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('category')"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="category-filter-box">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.DistinctBy(i => i.Category).OrderBy(i => i.Category))
                        {
                            var uniqueId = "category-" + item.Id;
                            <div class="filter-box-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="@uniqueId" name="car-category" value="@item.Category" />
                                <label for="car-category" class="control-label">@item.Category</label>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="year-filter box-filter" id="year">
                    <div class="filter-year d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4>ANNEE</h4>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('year')"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('year')"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="year-filter-box">
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="MinYear" name="MinYear" value="" placeholder="année min" />
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="MaxYear" name="MaxYear" value="" placeholder="année max" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="price-filter box-filter" id="price">
                    <div class="filter-price d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4>PRIX</h4>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('price')"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('price')"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="price-filter-box">
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="MinPrice" name="MinPrice" value="" placeholder="prix min" />
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="MaxPrice" name="MaxPrice" value="" placeholder="prix max" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="km-filter box-filter" id="km">
                    <div class="filter-km d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4>KILOMETRAGE</h4>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('km')"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('km')"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="km-filter-box">
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="MinKilometers" name="MinKilometers" value="" placeholder="km min" />
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="MaxKilometers" name="MaxKilometers" value="" placeholder="km max" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="energy-filter box-filter" id="energy">
                    <div class="filter-energy d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4>CARBURANT</h4>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('energy')"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('energy')"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="energy-filter-box">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.DistinctBy(i => i.Energy).OrderBy(i => i.Energy))
                        {
                            var uniqueId = "energy-" + item.Id;
                            <div class="filter-box-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="@uniqueId" name="car-energy" value="@item.Energy" />
                                <label for="car-energy" class="control-label">@item.Energy</label>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="gear-filter box-filter" id="gear">
                    <div class="filter-gear d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4>BOITE DE VITESSE</h4>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('gear')"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('gear')"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="gear-filter-box">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.DistinctBy(i => i.GearType).OrderBy(i => i.GearType))
                        {
                            var uniqueId = "gear-" + item.Id;
                            <div class="filter-box-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="@uniqueId" name="car-gear" value="@item.GearType" />
                                <label for="car-gear" class="control-label">@item.GearType</label>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="critair-filter box-filter" id="critair">
                    <div class="filter-critair d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4>CRIT'AIR'</h4>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('critair')"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('critair')"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="critair-filter-box">
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="0" name="car-critair-0" value="0" />
                            <label for="car-critair" class="control-label">0</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="1" name="car-critair-1" value="1" />
                            <label for="car-critair" class="control-label">1</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="car-critair-2" name="car-critair-2" value="2" />
                            <label for="car-critair-2" class="control-label">2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="car-critair-3" name="car-critair-3" value="3" />
                            <label for="car-critair-3" class="control-label">3</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="car-critair-4" name="car-critair-4" value="4" />
                            <label for="car-critair-4" class="control-label">4</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="car-critair-5" name="car-critair-5" value="5" />
                            <label for="car-critair-5" class="control-label">5</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="options-filter box-filter" id="options">
                    <div class="filter-options d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4>EQUIPEMENTS</h4>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-down" onclick="showFilter('options')"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-up" onclick="hideFilter('options')"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter-box-open limited-height" id="options-filter-box">
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="AirConditionner" name="AirConditionner" value="true" />
                            <label for="AirConditionner" class="control-label">Climatisation</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Bluetooth" name="Bluetooth" value="true" />
                            <label for="Bluetooth" class="control-label">Blutetooth</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ReversingRadar" name="ReversingRadar" value="true" />
                            <label for="ReversingRadar" class="control-label">Radar de recul</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Gps" name="Gps" value="true" />
                            <label for="Gps" class="control-label">GPS</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-box-item">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="SpeedRegulator" name="SpeedRegulator" value="true" />
                            <label for="SpeedRegulator" class="control-label">Régulateur de vitesse</label>
                        </div>
                            <div class="filter-box-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Abs" name="Abs" value="true" />
                                <label for="Abs" class="control-label">ABS</label>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

My partial View _CarPartial

```
<div class="cars-cards">
    @foreach (Car car in Model)
    {
        <div class="car-card card car-item">
            <div class="car-image-container">
                <img src="~/Uploads/CarImageCover/@car.CoverImage" class="card-img-top" alt="Image de couverture de la voiture">
            </div>
            <div class="car-card-body card-body d-block d-flex">
                <h3 class="card-text car-card-brand">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.Brand)</h3>
                <h4 class="card-text car-card-model">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.Model)</h4>
                <p class="card-text car-card-year-km">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.Year) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.Kilometers) km</p>
                <p class="card-text car-card-price">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => car.Price) €</p>
                <a class="see-more" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@car.Id">Voir l'annonce +</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

and my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var listCar = await _context.Cars.ToListAsync();
        return View(listCar);
    }
```

I'd like to apply the filters to the car list in the partial View. Any help is welcome, I'm starting to learn how to code and I'm kinda lost sometimes.

I tried few YT tutorials but they filtered only on one input text field and I have several filters to apply, mostyl checkboxes.

I also checked this post [What is the best way to render PartialView to a Layout Page in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968725/what-is-the-best-way-to-render-partialview-to-a-layout-page-in-mvc/38968860#38968860) but it isn't clear how to apply the filters on the partial view even if I understood that using a partial view is a good way to do it.

I also read about fetch API (and AJAX request) but I fail to see how to adapt it to my MVC.

Comment: What you're asking is *very* broad for a single Stack Overflow question.  If the overall goal is to start learning and using AJAX in your web application then you'd likely be best served by starting with some introductory tutorials and examples.  You don't necessarily need an example which specifically caters to your exact application, but rather examples which help familiarize you with the concepts and technologies which you can then apply to your scenario.

Comment: Yes I figured that out yesterday after posting my message. So I tried to learn little by little and I understood how AJAX calls work. In the end I could make it work this afternoon, thanks for your answer .